# Vagrant install docker with puppet

Tags: docker, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to install docker on the **trusty64** vagrant image:

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "apps.local"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    puppet module install garethr-docker
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision "puppet"
end
```

**manifests/default.pp**

```
include 'docker'

docker::image { 'ubuntu':
  image_tag => 'trusty'
}
```

And the output of `vagrant up` :

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppet/modules ...
==> default: Notice: Downloading from https://forge.puppetlabs.com ...
==> default: Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
==> default: /etc/puppet/modules
==> default: └─┬ garethr-docker (v5.3.0)
==> default:   ├── puppetlabs-apt (v3.0.0)
==> default:   ├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.17.0)
==> default:   └── stahnma-epel (v1.2.2)
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
==> default: Error: Syntax error at 'Variant'; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp:6 on node carcosa.local
==> default: Error: Syntax error at 'Variant'; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp:6 on node carcosa.local
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you log into vm using `vagrant ssh` and check puppet version?

Comment: 3.4.x generally ( I have tried trusty64 and xenial64 ), I have tried to install puppet 4.x but I don't succeed in installing it in any way...

Comment: @kitensei https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/puppet_collections.html#apt-based-systems to install non-obsolete Puppet on Trusty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is just to have docker installed on the VM, the easiest is to let vagrant install it. Vagrant has [docker provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html) and if not installed it will try to install

This simple Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision "docker"
end
```

will install docker on trusty64 - the provisioner has after many advantages if you want to work with docker images etc ...

Comment: this is indeed enough for me, but I'd like to understand why am I getting these errors, any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of [puppetlabs-apt module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt/1.6.0/readme) supports only the latest version of puppet

```
Latest version is compatible with:
 - Puppet Enterprise 2016.5.x, 2016.4.x
 - Puppet >= 4.7.0 < 5.0.0
 - Ubuntu, Debian
```

If you want to make if work in your example you need to force the installation of a version supported by puppet 3.x (see https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt/1.6.0/changelog)

The following `Vagrantfile` will do the work

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  #config.vm.provision "docker"

  config.vm.hostname = "apps.local"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    puppet module install puppetlabs-apt --version 2.4.0
    puppet module install garethr-docker
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision "puppet"
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your double answer, works perfectly now